# How to write a sql show the quantity result based on filter and merge two different column if no filtering option?

Tags: mysql

Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |   qty_ordered    |   qty_received   | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         30       |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         30       |         20       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I have a filter to let user choose whether to show qty_ordered or qty_received. When user select filter for qty_ordered then result will be 30 else if select qty_received then result will be 20 else will return 50.

SQL

```
select sum(qty_ordered) as order, sum(qty_received) as received from table...
```

Currently i will select both, and using if-else statement in my html to show the result of quantity. If filtering by qty_ordered and qty_received will be fine, but problem occurred when need to display all quantity. Mean, i need to merge ordered quantity and received quantity with same id as one row.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     quantity     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         50       |               
|---------------------|------------------|
```

ps: Ordered quantity will only be sum up if there is no received quantity.

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic

Comment: I did, sorry i will improve my question next time. Btw, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregating by the `ID` and using `SUM` to obtain single values for the quantity ordered and received:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered,
    SUM(qty_received) AS qty_received,
    SUM(COALESCE(qty_received, qty_ordered)) AS qty_total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID;

    ID  qty_ordered qty_received qty_total
1   10  60          20           50
```

I use a `COALESCE` trick in the expression for the total sum.  The logic is that if the quantity received is present, we count it, even if the quantity ordered might also be present.  If the quantity received be absent, only then do we count the quantity ordered.

### Demo

Comment: I tried, but output incorrect, total should be 50 but mine will show 51.

Comment: I tried to display single result from ordered and received, it shows correct output, but when sum up the result auto increase one.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I believe my query is valid for the data you showed us.  If you have other data then perhaps you should post it.

Comment: I have one condition, which some of the id will have both ordered quantity and received quantity, if there is received quantity then will sum up based on received quantity.

Comment: Are you saying for the purpose of the total, if a given record has both ordered and received quantity, use the receieved quantity?

Comment: Yes. Sorry i missed out this condition.

Comment: How can i use distinct if i am using coalesce? I need distinct to prevent duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. SUM(DISTINCT(COALESCE(qty_received, qty_ordered))) AS qty_total  . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zidance So there’s no chance that you might have duplicate values for both columns? That just seems weird.

Comment: @Strawberry You had it right; there is no primary key.  Without the duplicate requirement (whatever that means) we get away with it, but not with duplicates.

Comment: My bad, there is a PK in my table, i just show FK on this table. In order to get the output correct i will need distinct. Maybe my query was wrong. Anyway thanks.